# Calculating trendlines using slope and y-intercept

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a requirement in one of my project to draw trendlines on charts. I need to know in the below equations(where 'm' is slope and 'b' is y-intercept):

[Linear Trendline]: y = mx + b
[Logarithmic Trendline]: y = a*log(x) + b
[Polynomial Trendline]: y = a(n)x^n + a(n-1)x^(n-1) + a(1)x + a(0)
[Power Trendline]: y = a*x^b
[Exponential Trendline]: y = a*b^x

does the value of 'm' and 'b' can be calculated once and used in all of the equations or the values of 'm' and 'b' are calculated in a different way for every equation. If they are calculated differently for every equation, how are they calculated? Can someone provide me a link for that. Currently, I am using [this](http://classroom.synonym.com/calculate-trendline-2709.html) method to calculate 'm' and 'b'

Another question is how accurate are the other equations to calculate trendlines? Is there any other method that is more accurate than this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831456/calculating-trendlines-using-slope-and-y-intercept

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer all of your questions, but as to a linear trendline (step for step):

```
line = {{1., 3.}, {2., 5.}, {3, 6.5}};

a = Last@(Times @@ line);
b = Times @@ (Plus @@ line);
c = Total[(First /@ line)^2]*Length@line;
d = Total[(First /@ line)]^2;

slope = (a - b)/(c - d)
```

> 1.75

```
e = Total[Last /@ line];
f = slope*Total[First /@ line];
equation = slope x + intercept
```

> 1.33333 + 1.75 x

```
trend = Table[y, {x, 1, Length@line}];

ListLinePlot[{line, trend}, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"data", "trend"}]
```

[image]